# Quiero hacer una calculadora muy básica

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio sobre una calculadora básica, y una de las formas que se me ocurrió es la siguiente: pero me sigue marcando error en el  `.value` y no sé porque.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="David Martínez Espinosa">
    <title>Ciclos </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>

    <script>
        function suma(num1, num2) {
            var num1, num2;
            num1 = document.getElementById("valor").value;
            num2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;
            var sumado;
            return num1 + num2;
        }

        sumado = suma();
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "la suma de " + num1 + " y " + num2 + " es " +
            sumado;
    </script>

    Introduce el primer valor
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="valor" value="">
    <br> Introduce el segundo valor
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="valor2" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="suma()">
    <p id="resultado"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te da error porque estas llamando la funcion sin valores en los inputs.  No necesitas retornar el valor, puedes imprimir el resultado dentro de la funcion asi:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="David Martínez Espinosa">
    <title>Ciclos </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>

    <script>
        function suma(num1, num2) {
            var num1, num2;
            num1 = document.getElementById("valor").value;
            num2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;
            var sumado = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "la suma de " + num1 + " y " + num2 + " es " +
            sumado;
        }

        
        
    </script>

    Introduce el primer valor
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="valor" value="">
    <br> Introduce el segundo valor
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="valor2" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="suma()">
    <p id="resultado"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¡ya entendí!

Answer (score 1):

Si llamas la función `suma()` al dar clic al botón,

```
 <input type="button" value="+" onclick="suma()">
```

no necesitas definir que este recibirá valores.

```
  //function suma(num1, num2) {
  function suma() {
   ...
   ...
  }
```

Además la misma función  debe imprimir el resultado ya que si imprimes afuera de la función esta impresión del resultado solo se realizará al cargar la página.

Asegura también de usar la función `parseInt()` para convertir los valores de los input a entero y poder realizar correctamente la suma:

```
  function suma() {
       var num1, num2;
       //Obtiene valores.
       num1 = document.getElementById("valor").value;
       num2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;
       //Realiza suma.
       var sumado = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
       //muestra valor valor.  
       document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "la suma de " + num1 + " y " + num2 + " es " + sumado;
      }
```

Ejemplo:

```js
        function suma() {
            var num1, num2;
 
            num1 = document.getElementById("valor").value;
            num2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;

            var sumado = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);

        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "la suma de " + num1 + " y " + num2 + " es " + sumado;
        }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="David Martínez Espinosa">
    <title>Ciclos </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>
    Introduce el primer valor
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="valor" value="">
    <br> Introduce el segundo valor
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="valor2" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="suma()">
    <p id="resultado"></p>
</body>

</html>
```